# PHP Singleton class with PSR standards

Tags: php, mysql, oop, singleton, psr-4

I need your help.
I create Singleton class to manipulate with multidimensional arrays.
So I want you to review my class and add some recomendations about it.

The logic is working good, but now I am learning how to write a clear code with PSR standarts, I need to know if this moments are OK:

- Connecting with database
- Exceptions (Do I put them right?)
- Comments
- Singleton realisation
- ... maybe some other things

Thank you in advance.

```
/**
 * Class treeData
 * Singleton class for multidimensional arrays with user data
 */

class treeData
{

    protected static $_instance, $data, $pdo, $id;

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return treeData
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function getInstance($id) {
        if (self::$_instance === null) {
            self::$_instance = new self($id);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Try to create new instance of Singleton");
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Connection with DB
     * @return PDO
     */
    private static function db(){
        $host = '127.0.0.1';
        $db = 'for_test';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $charset = 'utf8';
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $pdo;
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    private static function getFromDb($id){
        $sql = "SELECT `data` FROM tree2 WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($id));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

        return $row;
    }

    /**
     * Save to DB
     */
    private static function saveToDb() {
        $sql = "UPDATE tree2 SET `data` = :data WHERE id = :id";
        $stmt = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => self::$id, ':data' => self::mySerialize(self::$data)));
    }

    /**
     * treeData constructor.
     * @param $id
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private  function __construct($id) {
        if(!is_int($id)){
            throw new Exception("User ID Must be INT");
        }
        self::$pdo = self::db();
        self::$id = $id;
        $row = self::getFromDb($id);
        $data = $row['data'];

        //Prepare data
        if(empty($data)){ //Array empty - creating new
            self::$data = array();
        } else{ //Working with data
            self::$data = self::myDeserialize($data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * For prevent clone
     */
    private function __clone() {
    }

    /**
     * For serialize
     * @param $data
     * @return string
     */
    private static function mySerialize($data){
        return json_encode(serialize($data));
    }

    /**
     * For Deserialize
     * @param $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    private static function myDeserialize($data){
        return unserialize(json_decode($data));
    }

    /**
     * Getting variable from private variable data
     * @param String $path
     * @return array
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function get($path){
        $pathArray = explode('/', $path); //Getting array with path
        $level = self::$data; //Begining array
        foreach ($pathArray as $key){
            if(array_key_exists($key, $level)){
                $level = $level[$key];
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Index '$key' does not exists");
            }
        }
        return $level;
    }

    /**
     * Setting new variable
     * @param $path
     * @param $value
     */
    public static function set($path, $value){
        //Getting path
        $pathArray = explode('/', $path);
        //Adding data to array
        $level =& self::$data;
        foreach ($pathArray as $key) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $level) or !is_array($level[$key])) {
                $level[$key] = [];
            }
            $level =& $level[$key];
        }
        if(is_array($level) && is_array($value)){
            $level = array_merge($level, $value);
        } else {
            $level = $value;
        }
        self::saveToDb();

    }

}
```

Comment: "So I want you to review my class and add some recomendations about it" That seems like more of a request for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/